# How to edit a process / activity of another application?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-service

With this I can see open applications (shows the package name and class name):

```
Context context = this.getApplicationContext();
    ActivityManager mgr = (ActivityManager)context.getSystemService(ACTIVITY_SERVICE);

    ConfigurationInfo config = mgr.getDeviceConfigurationInfo();
    List<RunningAppProcessInfo> processes = mgr.getRunningAppProcesses();
    List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = mgr.getRunningTasks(100);

    String runningTasks = "Running tasks: \n";

    for(Iterator i = tasks.iterator(); i.hasNext();){
        RunningTaskInfo p = (RunningTaskInfo)i.next();
        runningTasks += p.id + " " + p.baseActivity.flattenToString() + "\n";
    }

    System.out.println(runningTasks);
```

How I can access and edit a particular process?

For example, access com.whatsapp / Conversation and change the background color.
Is it possible to change the interface of an app "X" from another application not linked?

Comment: accessing other application features is not allowed

Comment: This is not possible due to the Android security model. One application cannot make changes in another application.

Comment: @D_Vaibhav I understand that is not allowed to do this for security and Google Play. 
But regardless of that concept, is it possible?

There are applications that display their activities over others, either in lockscreen or activities. I guess if you can do other activities on floating, it is possible to affect this activity.

Comment: @ephramd Displaying activity, layout above another running app don't access any of its data. As you want to change something inside another app which is not allowed for security reason